# What is the term for baptizing a person as a Sith? Or (officially) converting a Jedi to a Sith?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, sith

I've checked out some sources but I don't know, **Christening** kind of sounds like it's out of place. Doesn't Christen mean baptizing a person as a Roman Catholic or maybe any Christian denomination in the name of Christ the Lord for that matter? That's why it is called "Christ"-ening in the first place?

Other than what I mentioned above, googling for the definition of "Christen" says:

- dedicate (a vessel, building, etc.) ceremonially.
- use for the first time.

Okay, but to my knowledge, the concept of Roman Catholicism, Christian Church or existence (or knowledge of historical existence) of a Christ was never mentioned in the Star Wars universe. Meaning, that term couldn't have had an origin that would make the other two definitions above valid.

Is there an official term for Baptizing a.k.a. "Christening" (as some sources say) a person as a Sith?

Is there a "**Sithening**" or something?

Comment: +1 for the wordplay, but I'd actually like to see an answer to this one. I'll see if I can't uncover something. :)

Comment: Is there a canon term for someone becoming a jedi?

Comment: Anointing is the word that comes to mind.

Comment: @StuperUser That is actually a good question too!

Comment: @MichaelItzoe Actually a good answer. But I'm looking for an official term for it. :)

Comment: @anaranjada IMO, the whole [tag:Christian] tag could go, or be merged into [tag:religion].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there is no such term. There is no official ceremony nor a name for it. The apprentice (who does not necessarily have to be a Jedi who turned from the light) pledges himself to the Sith, and the Sith Master chooses a Sith name for his apprentice and gives him the title "Darth". This is how Anakin became the Sith Lord Darth Vader:

[image]

This is the text of that scene:

> Anakin: I pledge myself to your teachings. To the ways of the Sith.
>
> Palpatine: Good. Good. The Force is strong with you. A powerful Sith you will become. Henceforth, you shall be known as Darth . . . Vader.
>
> <sub>**Episode III: *Revenge of the Sith***</sub>

Anakin simply **pledges** himself to the Sith and Palpatine gives him his Sith name.

---

There is no mention of a term like "sithening" or any sort of conversion ceremony in any of the following Wookieepedia articles which might mention it:

- [Sith](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith/Canon)
- [Darth](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth/Canon)
- [Sith apprentice](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_apprentice/Canon)
- [Dark Lord of the Sith](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Lord_of_the_Sith/Canon)

Other than the Episode III scene, the closest descriptions of a conversion that I can find are some quotes from a Legends book, which simply says that the Master "chooses" the apprentice. For example:

> Bane’s Rule of Two ensured that the power of both Master and apprentice would grow from generation to generation until the Sith were finally able to exterminate the Jedi and usher in a new galactic age. That was why **Bane had chosen Zannah** as his apprentice: she had the potential to one day surpass even his own abilities.
>
> <sub>***Dynasty of Evil*, p. 9**</sub>

And also:

> The Master will train his apprentice in the ways of the Sith, until one day she must challenge him. If she proves unworthy, the Master will destroy her and **choose a new apprentice**.
>
> <sub>***Dynasty of Evil*, p. 153**</sub>

---

In summary, a conversion to the Sith would therefore simply be described as a "pledge", or a Master "choosing" an apprentice, or perhaps an "entitling" since the apprentice gains the title of "Darth".

(Also, the term "Christening" is not limited to Roman Catholicism -- it is used by many Christian denominations.)

Comment: From the Legends sources, most apprentices become Sith by killing their master or a previous apprentice. You could say that is a ceremony of sorts.

Comment: Thanks. I really like the detailed answer. Source links helped a lot too. I'm a hold off for one more day and see if someone else has a better answer.

Answer (score 8):

I kind of thought this was too obvious to actually be an answer, since no one else has mentioned it, I believe the term is "turning".  As in:

- Turning to the dark side.
- Do you think he can be turned (to the dark side)?
- If you could turn the boy, he would become a powerful ally...

Comment: Falling works as well.

Comment: @TGnat Actually really good...

Comment: "Turning" sounds like the best term for it. It's intuitive and if not only for the specifics of my answer where I'm looking for an official term, i would have chosen this. So i chose the other answer.